# VB.net Windows Service with File Watcher

Tags: windows, service

I have a windows service that runs at 5 PM everyday. Once it starts it will use a method to watcher that monitors a folder and if any new file is created it will upload it to Mainframes.

My questions is once the service is started for how long will the filewatcher be effective?? When will the service stop watching the folder.

What happens if someone creates a file at 7PM will it still upload to the mainframe??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "service" you mean a Windows Service (caps) as opposed to a "service" (scheduled executable). Of course this depends on the code in the service but ostensibly as long as the service is running, the filewatcher should monitor the folder.